# save data, code together?

Tags: r

I am reading in a file in SPSS format (.por), cleaning it in R and then exporting as a clean .csv file. Is it possible to save the code I am using to read/clean/export the data to save it along with the data? In other words, I want to be able to load the datafile at some later point and be able to recall exactly how it was created.

Comment: check out [video #016](http://www.twotorials.com/)  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it all from the console, here's a hack:

```
foo<-attributes(myfunc)$srcref
write.table(as.character(foo),'myfunc.txt')
```

Edit: to answer Paul's question, here's the output from one of my 'toys' .  The elements of each row (one element per pair of quotation marks)  are tab-separated.

```
"x"
"1" "function(x, numdig=3, na.rm=TRUE,printit=TRUE)"
"2" "{"
"3" "   x<-as.vector(x)"
"4" "   if (na.rm)   x <- x[!is.na(x)]"
"5" "   skewx<-theskew(x)"
"6" "   kurtosisx<-thekurt(x)"
"7" "   #allstats<-list(min=min(x), max=max(x), mean=mean(x), median=median(x),sdev=sd(x), skew=theskew(x), kurtosis=thekurt(x))"
"8" "   #looks nicer w/ dataframe rather than pure list"
"9" "   allstats<-data.frame(cbind(min=min(x), max=max(x), mean=mean(x), median=median(x),sdev=sd(x), skew=theskew(x), kurtosis=thekurt(x)),row.names='')"
"10" "  #too long for one line"
"11" "  if(printit)"
"12" "      {"
"13" "      print(format(allstats[1:4],digits=numdig))"
"14" "      print(format(allstats[5:7],digits=numdig))"
"15" "  }"
"16" "  return(invisible(allstats))"
"17" "  }"
```

I have not tried to find a console hack to convert that text back into function code, but I bet a simple  `gsub('"','',textobject[,2])` would work.

Comment: Hi Carl... I'm not sure I understand what's going on here. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @user702432 - I'm using `attributes` to retrieve some of the information "included" in any closure, aka function, object.  In this case, the attribute "srcref" contains the source code for the function.   Welcome to Object-Oriented Programming!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just save a set of files, a `.R` file with the R code, the `por` file with the SPSS data, and a `csv` file with the data, all starting with the same name:

```
spam.R
spam.por
spam.csv
```

To transport them, you could zip these files into `spam.zip`.

Alternatively, you could add the R code as comments above the data:

```
# here R code
# Some more code
here the csv data
```

`read.table` will automatically skip these lines as they start with a `#` (the standard comment character of `read.csv`).

Comment: This is quite neat, Paul. Thanks.